# Compress "page" label with varioref and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

In case of multiple cross-references of same kind (say sections), even if not consecutive, `cleveref`'s `\cref` command compresses the references' labels by using the plural form: for instance, `\cref{foo2,foo4,foo6}` could prints:

> sections 2, 4 and 6

instead of:

> section 2, section 4 and section 6

If `varioref` is also loaded, the page numbers can be added thanks to its `\vref` command (redefined by `cleveref`) used instead of `\cref`.

But, then, the "page" label is not compressed, as shown by the following MWE where `\vref{foo2,foo4,foo6}` prints:

> sections 2, 4 and 6 on page 4, on page 8 and on page 12.

where one could expect:

> sections 2, 4 and 6 on pages 4, 8 and 12.

especially since:

- `\cpageref` does the right job,
- `cleveref`'s documented code claims to use `\cpageref` instead of `\vpageref` in its redefinition of `\vref`:

  > Since `\cref` can cope with multiple references, we extend the page
  >   referencing magic of `\vref` et al. to use `\cpageref`
  >   instead, assisted by `\@setvpageref` and `\@vpagerefrange`
  >   (which typeset page references using `varioref` commands). The former takes care of multi-references, the latter take care of
  >   the `varioref` page referencing magic.

Do you see what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \section{#1}\label{#1}
  \newpage
  #1
  \newpage
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\cref{foo2,foo4,foo6}|: \cref{foo2,foo4,foo6}
\item \verb|\vref{foo2,foo4,foo6}|: \vref{foo2,foo4,foo6}
\item \verb|\cpageref{foo2,foo4,foo6}|: \cpageref{foo2,foo4,foo6}
\item \verb|\vpageref{foo2,foo4,foo6}|: \vpageref{foo2,foo4,foo6}
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\multido{\i=1+1}{6}{%
  \test{foo\i}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you mean that `\vref` need to be redefined in some way to be `\cref{#1} on \cpageref{#1}`. I think the best is to write to the author.

Comment: @touhami Indeed, and I have the secret hope he subscribed to the `cleveref` tag ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to limitations of `varioref`. Consecutive page references
*are* compressed when you use `varioref` with `cleveref`. But avoiding
printing "on page x" before each page reference (or group thereof) would mean rewriting large parts of `varioref`.

At that point, `cleveref` would probably be replacing `varioref` rather than
hooking into it. Perhaps this would make sense. But it's unlikely to happen any time soon.

Comment: When it will happen, `cleveref`'s users will likely be very happy :)